# How to read every 7 bits in a file as an integer?

Tags: c#

I have some files where every 7 bits represents a little-endian integer.

So far I have an implementation reading bytes into a byte array, converting to a string, using an looping index to put 7 characters in a BitArray, and doing 2^x depending on index of that, but that seems extremely slow (files are only 20KB but take over 5 minutes to parse) and also too many casts to be the best way.

Is there a way to read a group of 7 bits directly from a file?

Comment: I feel very, very, sorry for you

Comment: Is this a **packed** 7-bits (so bits 0-6 are the first integer, then bits 7-14 are the second integer), or is this a 7-bit-preserving system (so bits 0-6 are the first integer, bit 7 is ignored, and bits 8-15 are the following integer)?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us the code you have so far? Have you considered using a [profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) that might show you where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Could you use Stream.ReadAsync to read the files in chunks? This is assuming that you are CPU bound from your casts and 2^x operations.

Comment: Do you need random access or just sequential streaming?

Comment: Try looking at the [BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint.aspx) method.

Comment: @Dai packed, unfortunately ()dbc sequential ()Icemanind that looks like it skips the 8th bit ()Andrew I created them using an entirely different library and language a few years ago.

Comment: Who is the monster that created that file? Can you reach them? Or is this an exercise you need to solve?

Comment: Consider subclassing `Stream` and creating a wrapper that returns each 7 bits as a byte.  [`BufferedStream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/bufferedstream.cs) could be a model of how to do this.

Comment: A solution would involve combining each read `byte` into pairs and performing a bitwise AND with a mask that is shifted by 7 bits each time, then shifting the result back and yielding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If these 7-bit integers are not packed, then it's a simple matter of working with the least-significant 7-bits of each byte:

```
Byte b; Int32 nb;
while( (nb = reader.ReadByte()) != -1 ) {
    b = (Byte)nb;

    Byte value = b & 0x7F;
    yield return value;
}
```

If these are packed bytes, then it's more fun :)

You will need between 1 and 2 bytes to work with, to extract the values from. I'm assuming the input is a stream of `Byte` (represented using `IEnumerator` for API simplicity) where the 7-bits are packed like so:

```
7-bit  |0                                 |1                                 |2                                 |3                                 |4
Bytes  |0                                      |1                                      |2                                      |3
Bits   |0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |0
```

The algorithm is such:

1. Maintain a "bit index" (`bi`) which tells us what the bit offset is (in each byte) where the next 7-bit integer starts.
2. Read a byte (`b0`), take the first 7 bits and yield-return it.
3. Increment the bit-index by 7.
4. 7 + 7 is greater than 8 (the size of a byte) so we need another byte. Read another byte in and combine this (`b1`) with the previous byte (`b0`) into a 16-bit value that can be read all-at-once
5. Extract the next 7-bit value by reading bits (`bi + 7`) from it, shifting it to make it useful, then yield-returning it.
6. Repeat.

There are probably some bugs here, let me know if you find any!

```
public static IEnumerable<Byte> ReadPacked7BitInts(IEnumerator<Byte> inputBytes) {

    Int32 bi = 0; // bit-index

    if( !inputBytes.MoveNext() ) yield break;
    Byte b0 = inputBytes.Current;

    while( true ) {
        if( bi == 0 ) yield return b0 & 0x7F;
        if( bi == 1 ) yield return (b0 >> 1) & 0x7F;
        else {
            // Read another byte
            if( !inputBytes.MoveNext() ) yield break;
            Byte b1 = inputBytes.Current;
            UInt16 value = (UInt16)b0 | ((UInt16)b1 << 8);

            yield return ( value >> bi ) & 0x7F;
        }

        bi = (bi + 7) % 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: If thats your idea of fun, I'm staying away from any parties you throw ;)

Comment: you should probably change that move next inside the loop to `if(!inputBytes.MoveNext()) yield break;` (There are other small things that need fixing, like that other `return;` needs to be switched to a `yield break;` and a few casting errors between `int` and stuff like `byte` and `UInt16`)